# Prepend each line of a variable with a string

Tags: php

How can I prepend a string, say `'a'` stored in the variable `$x` to each line of a multi-line string variable using PHP?

Comment: Please, show us an example of the desired output.

Comment: I'll stick my neck out here and guess he using php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of your **each line** requirement, I would first split the string to an array using `explode`, then loop through the array and add text to the beginning of each line, and then turn the array back to a string using `implode`. As long as the number of lines is not very big, this can be a suitable solution.

Code sample:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $x);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = 'a' . $arr[$key];
}
$x = implode("\n", $arr);
```

Example at: http://codepad.org/0WpJ41LE

Comment: do you think 50 is going to be noticeable?

Comment: If you would take the entire HTML output of your script and used `str_split` to split it into an array of letters  then used `foreach` on the array and `echo` on each letter it still wouldn't be very noticeable. That's because modern computing is powerful.

Comment: None the less a dedicated C script written to do exactly the same things your PHP application does would runt hundreds of times faster. Which means two things: 1) even though the difference between a 1s pageload and a 1.2s pageload isn't felt it's there and it adds up 2) if you are careful about not wasting resources unless you gain something in return you can reallocate those resources into more clients served/second/server.

Comment: you could simply write `echo "a" . implode("\na", explode("\n", $x));` instead of iterating it.

Comment: Yeah but that would defeat the purpose i explained in my example: don't use this unless you want to do more than one simple operation in that `foreach`.

Answer (score 16):

Can also use:

```
echo preg_replace('/^/m', $prefix, $string);
```

The `/` are [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The `^` matches the [beginning of a string](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php). the `m` makes it [multiline](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rerOGh)

Comment: Seems to be a very good solution. Could you explain how the `'{^}m'` regexp works?

Comment: @Gordon perhaps using more common delimiters for RegEx would minimize confusion. If OP is learning he should find textbooks and examples that use matching notation. Also the curly braces have special meaning within RegEx notation and it may add to the confusion. This is not the sort of RegEx that really needs "alternate delimiters" because you are not escaping many occurrences of the usual delimiter inside the expression.

Comment: I agree that the curly braces are the most flexible and they need the least amount of escaping. But try to relate to a noobs pov and imagin that it'd have taken him another year or more to actually reach the article that explained this. Meanwhile he only saw `/regex/` not to mention the fact that it breaks PCRE compatibility.

Comment: @MihaiStancu wait, you mean … the noobs actually do research my answers instead of just copy and pasting them? that inspires some hope. thanks ;)

Comment: That's why I said it would've taken them a full year... they copy paste today, hit "I don't know how these go together" hell tomorrow, and start learning and researching after failing the first project.

Comment: @MihaiStancu my naive assumption is they just ask another question on SO ;)

Comment: Well I keep answering and the questions just keep getting less and less researched and more and more demanding. I guess it should be no wonder Stack Overflow has the Pavlov effect on people: "push button receive bacon".

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to achieve this.

One would be:

```
$multi_line_var = $x.str_replace("\n", "\n".$x, $multi_line_var);
```

Another would be:

```
$multi_line_var = explode("\n", $multi_line_var);
foreach($multi_line_var AS &$single_line_var) {
    $single_line_var = $x.$single_line_var;
}
$multi_line_var = implode("\n", $multi_line_var);
```

Or as a deceitfully simple onliner:

```
$multi_line_var = $x.implode("\n".$x, explode("\n", $multi_line_var));
```

The second one is dreadfully wasteful compared to the first. It allocates memory for an array of strings. It runs over each array item and modifies it. And the glues the pieces back together.

But it can be useful if one concatenation is not the only alteration you're doing to those lines of text.